# While chatting in a website do i get the receiver's ip or the website's server ip?

Tags: ip, chat

I was thinking that when I chat with someone on a website (eg: facebook.com) all the messages I send or receive are coming with the IP of the Facebook server not my friends IP, in other words the server plays as a middle host between us.

After reading a lot I heard something called client-to-client messaging and this (as I think) is capable of receiving the msgs sent by my friend with his IP and my friend receives my messages with my IP so the website is working just to control the flow.

I'm really confused, can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different forms of chat, so the answer varies by implementation/website.  The primary methods are either direct "client-to-client" chat where the web site provides the application interface and facilitates a handshake to introduce two users to each other (you don't know how to connect to person B, they don't know how to connect to you, but you both know how to connect to the site, and the site negotiates the two of you connecting to one another).  This has a huge benefit to site operators as it is a draw for them (go to my site and you can chat) but they aren't burdened with the overhead of actually handling/passing all the traffic.

The other most-seen method is more like you were originally thinking.  You can use Facebook as an example of this one.  You send a message and it goes to the site's server, is logged in their logs, stored in their databases, etc.  The message is also sent to the recipients by being available in the database when person B's app performs a lookup.  There are hooks and callbacks that let the recipient know a new message is waiting, and their app downloads it as soon as it is notified, giving the appearance of instant direct messaging; but in reality this is all served as content by the hosting site.

An easy tell.  Direct client-to-client messages won't have history that follows you to different browsers (the application may store chat history on the local machine, but it won't follow to a different machine because that other machine wasn't part of the original direct communication).  Chat routed-through/stored-on a web site most often does have previous chat history that will follow you around (because you chats are all sent into and saved on the site, again Facebook is a great example).

Comment: you mean there are two kinds of chat: 
1) client to client which consists of linking the two users together through the website
2) a messaging method like facebook chat is that the client should look up for new msgs instead the sites forwards it to him directly

Comment: There are other message delivery schemes that are available (and I've seen used) for IM, but these two are the most common.  And yes, as you say, 1) is a direct link between the clients of the chatting people, while 2) is more of a one-on-one bulletin board: you post to a common server, the other person's client downloads from the common server, vice versa, just with polish to make it appear in "real time."  Other methods are rather rare (unless your aim is fully anonymous communication, then they become more popular than these two)

Comment: Thanks @Ruscal for your answer, it was very helpful.. Much appreciate it :)